# How can I get the NAT gateway public IP using the AWS CLI?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jq, aws-cli

Given a VPC id; I'm using AWS CLI and jq to derive the NAT Gateway address for the given VPC id. Here is what I have so far:

```
aws ec2 describe-nat-gateways --region='${aws_region}' | jq -r --arg efs_name ${vpcid} '.[] | .[] | select(.VpcId==$vpcid) | {nats: .NatGatewayAddresses}'
```

And the output is:

```
{
  "nats": [
            {
             "PublicIp": "52.34.207.107",
             "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-0bc0d320",
             "AllocationId": "eipalloc-fa7739c0",
             "PrivateIp": "172.20.130.224"
            }
          ]
}
```

Is there a way to get the `PublicIp` directly using the AWS CLI filters for the nat-gateways resource?

Answer (score 5):

Use `--query` to extract a field:

```
aws ec2 describe-nat-gateways --query 'NatGateways[*].NatGatewayAddresses[*].PublicIp'
```

Comment: You can use this to get the Tag name and few other information 
`aws ec2 describe-nat-gateways --query 'NatGateways[].{NatGatewayId:NatGatewayId,Tag_Name:Tags[].Value |[0],Public_IP:NatGatewayAddresses[].PublicIp | [0],CreateTime:CreateTime}'`

Answer (score 3):

Since this question has the jq tag, here are some ways to extract the "PublicIp" value (or perhaps values), given a JSON text as shown:

1) All such values

```
.nats[] | .PublicIp
```

or

```
.. | objects | .PublicIp
```

2) First such value

Wrap either of the above in a call to `first`.